# add a value to the end of the array array<String^>^ c++ winform

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

how to add a value to the end of the array part before dataGridView1->Rows->Add(part);

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rw->Length; i++)
                    {
                    array<String^>^ part = rw[i]->ToString()->Split(L',');
                        dataGridView1->Rows->Add(part);
                    }
```

value from countprodtextBox->Text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the size of an array.
But you can create a new array with an increased length, copy the original array over, and assign the last element.

```
array<String^>^ copy = gcnew array<String^>(part->Length + 1);
for (int j = 0; j < part->Length; ++j)
    copy[j] = part[j];
copy[copy->Length-1] = ...
```

Btw: your index `i` will run out of bounds. You have to replace `<=` by `<`.

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly create the array and then add elements to it :-

Before for loop :-

string** part = new string[rw->Length][];

In the for loop before adding to datagridview :-

part[i] = rw[i]->ToString()->Split(L',');